# wapsite on Sony ericcson P1i

Tags: sony

On the sony ericcson p1i the Wapsite is not opening properly? On rest all it is working fine. Is it a browser featue or a problem at our end. Please suggest a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which browser? The inbuilt browser or any other browser? if its any other browser then check using the same browser in other phones.

For a phone like p1i I dont think sites wont be displayed properly so it might be your issue. Please provide more info about the error.

BTW website not displaying properly is a bug not a feature ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem description is not very easy to understand, but I assume that your problem is that for one specific site wap pages will not show properly. This could be a local problem with the wap browser. One way to eliminate that is to use another browser than the internal one. Try to download [Opera Mini](http://www.opera.com/mini/download/) or [Opera Mobile](http://www.opera.com/mobile/download/) and open the site with that. If that works, it is clearly a problem with the local wap browser.

Answer (score 0):

it was some issue at the gateway end.
after which it is woking properly....